# In which init level /etc/profile or /etc/environment files are read?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, init-script

**TL:DR**: In which init level /etc/profile or /etc/environment files are read?

I want to create a service (`/etc/init.d/myservice`) starting a shell script located at `/opt/myservice/myservice.sh`. However this location (`/opt/myservice/`) is defined at installation time, so it's not a fixed location.

Let's say that I set an environment variable in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment` like `MYSERVICE_PATH=/opt/myservice`, set `# Default-Start: 3 4 5` on `/etc/init.d/myservice` file.

Could I safely assume that `$MYSERVICE_PATH` will always be available at those init levels (3,4,5), so my init script could call `sh $MYSERVICE_PATH/myservice.sh`?

Comment: `/etc/profile` is only read upon login.  What you _can_ do is have your installer drop a configuration file in `/etc/` (for example, `/etc/myapplication.conf`) that the startup script can read for installation location and other relevant information.

Comment: Why not simply create `/etc/init.d/myservice` on installation?

Comment: Thank you for answering @DopeGhoti. I think your answer is the right answer. Could you provide an answer with some more technical details? This way I could accept yours as the correct answer and upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for answering @michas. I'm trying to do this, but I'm not a "full fledged" shell script developer. :-)

Comment: My pleasure.  I've gone ahead and written up a longer version of my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking in the wrong place to store application configuration information.

`/etc/profile` is used for the configuration of default settings for login shells (e. g. when SSHing in and invoking `bash` as the login shell).  It purpose is not for the configuration of application installation locations and the like.

`/etc/` as a whole, is, however, exactly that.  What is probably the best way to accomplish what you are looking for is to define a configuration file which always lives at e. g. `/etc/myservice.conf`, which might look something like:

```
# Configuration file for the My Service daemon
#
# Default settings:
#   myservice_root - The directory in which the service is installed
#                    Default:  /var/run/myservice
#   myservice_port - The TCP port upon which the service listens for incoming connecitons
#                    Default:  55321
myservice_root=/opt/myservice
myservice_port=6466
```

Your application, then, can always look at `/etc/myservice.conf` for its configuration, no matter what location on the filesystem it happens to be installed into, and other system administrators can instantly see what the file is for and what options are available to be reconfigured.